# Java XML parser?

Tags: java, xml

I'm currently converting a program I wrote in Visual Basic .NET (the 2005 variety) into Java. It used built-in XML methods to parse and generate the user's saved data, does Java have an equivalent feature built in or am I going to have to change file processing implementations? (I'd rather not, there's a lot of code I'd have to change.)

Comment: The main XML parsers I know are DOM and SAX, which are very different from eachother. Try looking those up and see if any of them fits you.

Comment: Java also includes a StAX parser.  A StAX parser is similar to a SAX one, the difference being with StAX you pull events, and with SAX the events are pushed to you.

Comment: If, as your comments indicate, you want to use XPath, why don't you simply google for "Java XPath"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Java can parse XML. Here's an example that takes in a String that contains XML and builds a [`Document`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) object out of it:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

You can then use the XPath API to query the dom. Here's a [tutorial/writeup](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) about it.

As far as serializing objects to XML, the official implementation is JAXB and it is part of Java since 1.6. [Here's](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/MarshalJavaobjecttoxmlandoutputtoconsole.htm) a simple example. It will let you serialize and deserialize to and from XML.

You can also create a DOM object manually and add nodes to it, but it's a little more tedious:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element rootNode = document.createElement("root");

Element childNode = document.createElement("child");
childNode.setTextContent("I am a child node");
childNode.setAttribute("attr", "value");

rootNode.appendChild(childNode);
document.appendChild(rootNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean that the properties/structure was generated through the classes/beans themselves? If so, then the answer is no [without an third party component]. I've used XStream before, and that is about the closest that I've gotten to .NET's XML Class serialization.

Comment: Java includes a JAXB implementation (JSR-222) for converting objects to/from XML.

Comment: I used XPath in the VB.NET version. It allowed writing an XML document by just asking for the current tag name, then the data, then when the tag should end, it automatically dealt with indenting and child tags without any input from the programmer.

Comment: @Casey Java has an XPath API. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Blaise: I forgot about that one. I got the impression that XStream was a little simpler.

Comment: @monksy - Check out my post on JAXB and XStream:   http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html.  I'll admit my bias that I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, but I feel the article is fair to XStream.