# XML reading in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Java XML library do you recommend (to replace dom4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831865/what-java-xml-library-do-you-recommend-to-replace-dom4j)

I have been googeling for some days now and can't seem to find the right answer to my challenge.

This is what the items in my xml file looks like.

```
<Item ItemNo="319097" Name="PCB SIO_1" Value="" Config="1" />
```

I would like to take every single part of this item line and break down into strings like this:

```
 String ItemNo = "319097";
```

So that I can create a string array that consists of the values in side the "" in the item node of the XML file.

Is this possible?

In advance thanks for helping me.

Comment: You can use the JDOM library to parse the document. There are lots of code snippets for that in the internet.

Comment: Possible [duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153422/java-xml-parser)

Comment: Presonally, I would use XSLT for that, not Java, but that is only my opinion.

Comment: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

Comment: "Googling for days"?  Crazy.  "Challenge"?  I think not.

Comment: What did you google?? `XML`? Try `how to parse XML attributes in Java`. Bingo! 25 million tutorials. And you even have about 50 possible ways to do it!

Comment: @duffymo Challenge to because I don't know how ;)
LukasEder I actually didn't know it is called "parse" but thanks for the tip...

Comment: Java is not an acronym and should not be set in all caps. Also, `how to read XML attributes in Java` produces a comparable number of relevant results. Or `how to interpret XML with Java`. Or any other phrasing I can conceive of, really. Also, you tagged your `xml-parse` which is in fact a new tag, so I find your claim "I actually didn't know it is called 'parse'" quite dubious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleaneast way would be to unmarshall the XML using Jaxb or something like Xstream : you create a Java object that represent your XML and then Jaxb will create an object and populate it with the XML values.
An example for your XML would be :

```
public class Item {
   private String itemNo;
   private String name;
   private String value;
   private String config;
   ... GETTERS / SETTERS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM API (among others) to select all `Item` elements and then go though the attributes. A nice library for this is Dom4j. You can find some useful code snippets here: http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html